# How to generate links in Angular UI Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been continuing learning angular and have now used the angular ui bootstrap pagination successfully. I am able to display the list of items together with the correct number of pages. And also switch to the correct page whenever I click on the pagination.

Now my question is if a user wanted to bookmark a certain page, or to make sure the user stays on the same page whenever he refreshes the browser, how do I go about it. There are no links (href) being generated on the address bar of the browser. Do I also need to set routes? Can you please post some examples, as it would greatly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Use HTML5 [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) so that the URL is the serialized state of your web application.

Answer (score 12):

You need to set up routes, you can do it using [routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) or [ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

In this example, I use route provider to demonstrate, but the idea is the same.

Here I set up a route with `currentPage` as parameter:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page/:currentPage', {
        templateUrl: "template.html",
        controller: PaginationDemoCtrl
    })
});
```

In your controller, you can retrieve the current page from `$routeParam`:

```
$scope.currentPage = $routeParams.currentPage || 1; //default to 1 if the parameter is missing
//load your paged data from server here.
```

You could just `$watch` current page for changes and update the location accordingly:

```
$scope.$watch("currentPage",function(value){
     if (value){
        $location.path("/page/" + value);
     }
  })
```

[Source code](http://plnkr.co/edit/NAgmuIHMJvix7BS3pKnu?p=preview)

[DEMO link](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/NAgmuIHMJvix7BS3pKnu/#/page/3)

With routing, you also need to update your code to load paged data from server. We don't load data immediately when the `currentPage` changes (in this case is the $watch function). We load our paged data when we retrieve the `$routeParam.currentPage` parameter.

As requested by @Harry, here is another solution to generate href links by overwriting bootstrap html template:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page/:currentPage?', {
        templateUrl: "template.html",
        controller: PaginationDemoCtrl
    })
})
.run(["$templateCache","$rootScope","$location", function($templateCache,$rootScope,$location) {

  $rootScope.createPagingLink = function(pageNumber){
    return "#" + $location.path().replace(/([0-9])+/,pageNumber);
//Here is a sample function to build href paths. In your real app, you may need to improve this to deal with more case.
  }

  $templateCache.put("template/pagination/pagination.html",
    "<ul class=\"pagination\">\n" +
    "  <li ng-if=\"boundaryLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noPrevious()}\"><a ng-href=\"{{$root.createPagingLink(1)}}\">{{getText('first')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "  <li ng-if=\"directionLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noPrevious()}\"><a ng-href=\"{{$root.createPagingLink(page - 1)}}\">{{getText('previous')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "  <li ng-repeat=\"page in pages track by $index\" ng-class=\"{active: page.active}\"><a ng-href=\"{{$root.createPagingLink(page.number)}}\">{{page.text}}</a></li>\n" +
    "  <li ng-if=\"directionLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noNext()}\"><a ng-href=\"{{$root.createPagingLink(page + 1)}}\">{{getText('next')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "  <li ng-if=\"boundaryLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noNext()}\"><a ng-href=\"{{$root.createPagingLink(totalPages)}}\">{{getText('last')}}</a></li>\n" +
    "</ul>");
}]);
```

[Source code](http://plnkr.co/edit/co1fYOONMrDiZfj4oo7n?p=preview)

[DEMO link](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/co1fYOONMrDiZfj4oo7n/#/page/1)

Comment: Still doesn't change your href.

Comment: @Harry: sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Please specify.

Comment: You're changing the url in javascript, which is not good practice. You need proper links so that bots can index it correctly.

Comment: @Harry: I agree that using rendering proper hrefs is good in this case (changing route url). Fortunately, It looks like that bots now run js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287476/why-do-search-engine-crawlers-not-run-javascript

Comment: @Harry: if bots could not run JS, bots could not index angular applications either.

Comment: Even if the bot can run js, which my phantomjs bot certainly can, it will not index the link if it's missing the href.

Comment: @Harry: yes, that's true. Anyway, this question is not about bots indexing.

Comment: The question is about generating links and you're advising something that's bad practice. :D

Comment: @Harry: I'm not sure if it makes sense to index all pages of a list like that. Imagine a situation when there is a lot more content on the page besides the list. In this case, bots will index also these content for each page. Should we provide a html snapshot containing all records when bots visit our page?

Comment: @Harry: it's possible to overwrite bootstrap's template to render hrefs. I'm still trying to remove the hardcoded "/page" in the href using something dynamic like $location.path(). See my edit

Comment: @Harry: See my edit with a solution to build href as you requested (remove the hardcoded "/page" by using location.path())

Comment: Thanks I ended up replacing the entire directive. I'll give you the bounty when I'm allowed to in 15 hours.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with the $location, without needing $route.

Here is an example of how to call the pagination from Angular UI Bootstrap:

```
<pagination ng-model="Controls.currentPage"
            total-items="Controls.totalItems"
            items-per-page="Controls.videosPerPage"
            max-size="5"
            rotate="false"
            boundary-links="true"
            ng-change="pageChanged()">
</pagination>
```

Inside the pageChanged() function, use the following to create a unique URL for your results page:

** My code is on Coffeescript, but the logic is simple and the code easy to adapt **

```
$location.search('page', $scope.Controls.currentPage)
```

And on your controller, use the following to check, when starting, if the URL parameter is there:

```
urlParams = $location.search()
if urlParams.page?
  $scope.Controls.currentPage = urlParams.page
else
  $scope.Controls.currentPage = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want your app to allow linking into certain states then you will have to have your app leverage the routeProvider.

The official docs don't have a great deal of information on routes but the tutorial has this page:

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Also John Lindquist's excellent short video tutorials are a must watch. One dealing with routes is:

http://www.egghead.io/video/gNtnxRzXj8s

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have watched several excellent videos of John Lindquist and I'll be sure I can use the stuff he shared on those videos. But my primary question was how should I go about generating links using the angular ui pagination? Sorry if it was not clear on my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Here the generic solution - the `uibPagination` directive decorator and the updated template:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.pagination')
    .config(function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('uibPaginationDirective', function($delegate, $templateCache) {
            var directive = $delegate[0];
            directive.scope.getPageHref = "&";
            $templateCache.put("uib/template/pagination/pagination.html",
                "<li ng-if=\"::boundaryLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"pagination-first\"><a ng-href=\"{{noPrevious() ? '' : getPageHref()(1)}}\" ng-disabled=\"noPrevious()||ngDisabled\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('first')}}</a></li>\n" +
                "<li ng-if=\"::directionLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"pagination-prev\"><a ng-href=\"{{noPrevious() ? '' : getPageHref()(page - 1)}}\" ng-disabled=\"noPrevious()||ngDisabled\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('previous')}}</a></li>\n" +
                "<li ng-repeat=\"page in pages track by $index\" ng-class=\"{active: page.active,disabled: ngDisabled&&!page.active}\" class=\"pagination-page\"><a ng-href=\"{{getPageHref()(page.number)}}\" ng-disabled=\"ngDisabled&&!page.active\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{page.text}}</a></li>\n" +
                "<li ng-if=\"::directionLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"pagination-next\"><a ng-href=\"{{noNext() ? '' : getPageHref()(page + 1)}}\" ng-disabled=\"noNext()||ngDisabled\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('next')}}</a></li>\n" +
                "<li ng-if=\"::boundaryLinks\" ng-class=\"{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}\" class=\"pagination-last\"><a ng-href=\"{{noNext() ? '' : getPageHref()(totalPages)}}\"  ng-disabled=\"noNext()||ngDisabled\" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{::getText('last')}}</a></li>\n" +
                "");
            return $delegate;
        });
    });
```

We decorate the directive with the `getPageHref` function passed from the outer scope which is used to construct the page links.

Usage:

```
<div ng-controller="ProductController">
    ...
    <ul uib-pagination
        total-items="totalItems"
        ng-model="page"
        get-page-href="getPageHref">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now you have to define the `getPageHref` function in your outer scope:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('ProductController', function($scope) {
    ...
    $scope.getPageHref = function(page) {
        return '#/products?page=' + page;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make code look better you can use `template-url` attribute on `uib-pagination` element 
to specify your new template url

I whould use `ui-sref` instead of using a function to generate the link .

and instead of reloading the controller for each page click pass a function for `ng-click` with `$event`so you could prevent the href from been executed
with `e.preventDefault()` and calling your ajax before

```
<li ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active}"><a ui-sref="list({page: page.text})"  ng-click="$root.paginationClick(page.number,$event)">{{page.text}}</a></li>
```