# Is text in an collapsed accordion with lazy load visible to search engines?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Does anyone know here how this is handled by typical bots such as Google?

I have a page with all my content in Bootstrap collapsed accordion sections. The content within the accordions is loaded with jQuery upon uncollapsing the section. Will this be followed by search engines?

```js
equipment_loaded = false;

function addAccordionListeners() {
    var collapseEquipment = document.getElementById('collapseEquipment');

    if (collapseEquipment && !equipment_loaded) {
        collapseEquipment.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse', function () {   
            phpFile = 'mequipment_content.php';
            $('#equipment-load-div').load('/presentation/mobile/' + phpFile);
            equipment_loaded = true;
        });
    }
}
```

```php
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingEquipment">
  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseEquipment" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEquipment">
    <?php echo $textHome[2];?>
  </button>
</h2>
<div id="collapseEquipment" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingEquipment" data-bs-parent="#mMainAccordion">
    <div class="accordion-body">
        <div id="equipment-load-div">
            <div class="spinner-border"> <span class="visually-hidden">Loading... </span> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related question, but was closed as off topic: [Why do search engine crawlers not run javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287476/why-do-search-engine-crawlers-not-run-javascript)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks, I didn't find this.